# Is it a good idea to put copyright symbol on charts and graphs?

Tags: copyright, design

I know that charts and graphs, etc. are not protected by copyright.

But I can still put something like *© x.com* next to the title of the chart. I want to do this so that people can still copy and use the chart, but not pass it off as their own - since the chart presents some information that is not immediately obvious from the available data and not everyone who saw that data would have thought of computing/deriving that information.

The question is, is it a good idea to do this? Or does it appear too *miserly* (for lack of a better word) to try to put a © notice on something that's not legally copyrightable. This is **not** a legal question obviously.

Comment: The question would probably have been better phrased as what sort of licensing can I use for non-copyrightable material like charts and graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't going to enforce a copyright claim, don't use a copyright mark.

Instead you could put something like `source: x.com`

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/) for this use case. Depending on the licence you would just be saying: "Please acknowledge I did this, even though I don't want any retribution and I am ok with anyone usin this chart."

Claiming copy**right** would be useless since you can't legally own rights on the graph, (although most people would honor your copyrights since graph/chart/table exemption from intellectual property is not widespread knowledge) but writing your own licence (CC) is a statement of your desires, and people will be more willing to respect CC atribution, whether they are aware of IP exemptions.